# Spring Boot Microservices are unable to connect to Axon Server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, axon

I have a Spring Boot microservices project with three microservices to test saga pattern for distributed transactions management.

When I run `Axon Server` locally with `java -jar axonserver.jar` and spring boot microservices with `mvn spring-boot:run`, everything is ok and I can see all microservices in Axon Server dashboard.

I have added `Docker` file for microservices and a `docker-compose.yml` into project to run the whole project with docker-compose. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  axonserver:
    image: axoniq/axonserver
    hostname: axonserver
    container_name: axonserver
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data
        target: /data
      - type: bind
        source: ./events
        target: /eventdata
      - type: bind
        source: ./config
        target: /config
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - '8024:8024'
      - '8124:8124'
      - '8224:8224'
    networks:
      - axon-demo      

  order-service:
    container_name: "order-service"
    build:
      context: ./order-service
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - axonserver
    networks:
      - axon-demo      

  payment-service:
    container_name: "payment-service"
    build:
      context: ./payment-service
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - axonserver
    networks:
      - axon-demo      

  shipping-service:
    container_name: "shipping-service"
    build:
      context: ./shipping-service
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - axonserver
    networks:
      - axon-demo      

networks:
  axon-demo:
    driver: bridge
```

I also added axon-server to `application.properties` of all microservices as below:

```
axon.axonserver.servers=axonserver:8124
```

After running `docker-compose up --build` command, microservices are unable to connect to the Axon server and I get this error:

```
order-service       | 2021-07-10 15:01:01.199  WARN 1 --- [rverConnector-0] o.a.a.c.AxonServerConnectionManager      : Connecting to AxonServer node localhost:8124 failed: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

My question is why microservices are looking for axon server in `localhost:8124` that is obviously wrong and is against their configurations in `application.properties`:

```
axon.axonserver.servers=axonserver:8124
```

Here `axonserver` is the container name of Axon server.

Comment: Have you tried to run only AxonServer from docker and your service from a jar to see if it works? Are you able to access AS dashboard (http://localhost:8024/)? I am not sure how you are bundling `application.properties` on your services but the problems seems to be there.

Comment: When I start all with java and maven everything works fine. When I start all with docker-compose, I can see AS dashboard but services are unable to connect. As you said I think that problem is somewhere within services and application.properties are completely ignored. any idea? I can share code with you on github.

Comment: This is github repository: https://github.com/alibehzadian/axon-server-dockerized

Comment: The project uses some non-public dependencies and I am not able to build them (` Could not resolve dependencies for project com.progressivecoder.ordermanagement:shipping-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`). Nonetheless, looking at it, seems like your `Dockerfile` is overriding the config location and pointing to the `config` folder on your root. Since that config does not have the `axon.axonserver.servers` property, it is falling back to the default which is `localhost:8124`. Can you try to rework it and see if it works?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `core-apis` which was the missing dependency I mentioned above. And my point is right, I've removed the `"--spring.config.location=/config/"` from the `Dockerfile` of the `order-service` and now it can connect successfully and I can see it on the AS dashboard. That should fix your problem. Should I add it as an answer for you?

Comment: You are right. The problem is in my Dockerfile. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is on your `Dockerfile` where you are overriding the `spring.config.location`. By removing that from the `Dockerfile`, the problem should is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties file contains the following:

```
axon.axonserver.servers=${AXONSERVER_HOST:axonserver:8124}
```

Please try it without the ":8124":

```
axon.axonserver.servers=${AXONSERVER_HOST:axonserver}
```

I think Spring boot is confused by the double ":". Port 8124 is the default for Axon Server connections, so you can leave it out without problems.

Comment: thank you. I have tested with ignored env. variables: "axon.axonserver.servers=axonserver:8124" with no success.