# Microservice not able to connect to AXON Server running as docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, axon

I have discovery service: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/API-MicroServices-Kafka/tree/master/Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka/DiscoveryService

I have product service: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/API-MicroServices-Kafka/tree/master/Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka/ProductsService

Following is my **docker-compose.yml** file: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/API-MicroServices-Kafka/tree/master/Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  axon-server:
    image: axoniq/axonserver
    container_name: axon-server
    ports:
      - 8124:8124
      - 8024:8024
    networks:
      - axon-demo

  discovery-service:
    build:
      context: ./DiscoveryService
    container_name: discovery-service
    ports:
      - 8010:8010
    networks:
      - axon-demo

networks:
  axon-demo:
    driver: bridge
```

When i run the following command `docker-compose up`, I get **axon-server** and **discovery-service** running.

I now run ProductService using the following file `src/main/java/com/appsdeveloperblog/estore/ProductsService/ProductsServiceApplication.java` which is under https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/API-MicroServices-Kafka/tree/master/Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka/ProductsService.

It works fine.

The problem start when I try to run ProductService as a microservice, and it fails to connect to axon server. To do that I modify the **docker-compose.yml** as follows:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  axon-server:
    image: axoniq/axonserver
    container_name: axon-server
    ports:
      - 8124:8124
      - 8024:8024
    networks:
      - axon-demo

  discovery-service:
    build:
      context: ./DiscoveryService
    container_name: discovery-service
    ports:
      - 8010:8010
    networks:
      - axon-demo

  product-service:
    build:
      context: ./ProductsService
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    depends_on:
      - axon-server
      - discovery-service
    networks:
      - axon-demo

networks:
  axon-demo:
    driver: bridge
```

Now if I try to run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
product-service_1    | 2021-08-20 03:06:27.973  INFO 1 --- [@29db04f6c0a4-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Requesting connection details from localhost:8124
product-service_1    | 2021-08-20 03:06:30.004  WARN 1 --- [@29db04f6c0a4-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Connecting to AxonServer node [localhost:8124] failed: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

I have gone through the following link, [Spring Boot Microservices are unable to connect to Axon Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328914/spring-boot-microservices-are-unable-to-connect-to-axon-server), which looks like similar problem but still not able to fix my problem.

Please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: It clearly reads `INFO` ...which is not an error.

Comment: product-service_1    | 2021-08-20 03:06:30.004  WARN 1 --- [@29db04f6c0a4-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Connecting to AxonServer node [localhost:8124] failed: UNAVAILABLE: io exception

Comment: Are you using `extension-springcloud`? What are you trying to achieve using both `Axon Server` and `Eureka`? Using only Axon Server should be enough and your applications should connect fine to that without the need of the `Eureka`.

Comment: @LucasCampos I have implemented SAGA pattern. There are multiple micro services that are behind the API Gateway and load balance, that is why i have used Eureka. I did not mention these details in original question, as it was not relevant but if you will look at different folders inside the GitHub, you will see more services. Actually I am have implemented SAGA Pattern with Spring Boot Micro services + Event Streaming using Apache Kafka. I am trying to containerize all the services and related components. Hope  that has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes and it works fine now.

In the file `ProductsService\src\main\resources\application.properties`

Old Entry: `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8010/eureka`

New Entry: `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://discovery-service:8010/eureka`

Added the following line in the above file: `axon.axonserver.servers=axon-server:8124`

In the File:  `Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka\docker-compose.yml`

Old Entry: version: "3.8"

New Entry: version: "2"

Added following code in yml file

```
   product-service:
    build:
      context: ./ProductsService
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    networks:
      - axon-demo
```

I have also checked in the code in git. The micro services can talk to each other, and connect to axon server and the problem reported earlier is resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.
Try to add to each service in application.properties

```
axon.axonserver.servers=localhost:8124
```

and to each service which connects to axon-server in docker-compose.yml
in environment variables section

```
axon-server:
    image: axoniq/axonserver
    container_name: axon-server
    ports:
      - 8124:8124
      - 8024:8024

product-service:
    ...
    environment:
      AXON_AXONSERVER_SERVERS: axon:8124
```